# Javascript function: change value of a single variable InPlace

Tags: javascript, function

The function reverseArrayInPlace(array) is as per solution in eloquentJS. The reverseArrayInPlace function works, by altering the arrayValue as expected. A similar function written for a single variable does not work as expected. In the code, x should come out as 25, but comes out as 20.

```
//function from eloquentJS solutions, working as expected
``    function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
      for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
        let old = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
      }
      return array;
    }
    let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
    console.log(arrayValue);
    // working as expected, returns → [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    
    // Writing similar function for a single variable
    
    function changeInPlace(a) {
      a += 5;
      return a;
    }
    let x = 20;
    changeInPlace(x);
    console.log(x);
    // Not working as expected returns, 20 instead of 25

   

    
     
    
`
```

[Snippet of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjPue.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning your calculated variable and not logging it. The one you are logging remains 20.

You must use your function as below :

```
let variable = changeInPlace(x)
```

Full code must be like :

```
function changeInPlace(a) {
  a += 5;
  return a;
}
let x = 20;
x = changeInPlace(x);
console.log(x);
// x should come out as 25
```

If for any reason you want to edit a variable value directly, you must access it globally like this:

```
function changeInPlace() {
    x += 5;
    return x;
}
let x = 20;
changeInPlace(x);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: True, but i want to build a function that alters a value of a variable.
If you notice-
let arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);
console.log(arrayValue);

provides the required result, without saving the function output to a new array

Comment: @Abhay In this case you must access variable globally in your function. Il will edit the response to show you.

Comment: please look at the function reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);

Comment: @Abhay you must notice that this is the default behavior of javascript langage. If array is passed to a function, it don't copy the array. Instead it use a reference. Which means that altering the array will alter the original array.

But this is not the case for a simple variable declared with let which copy the value of the variable passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Assign changeInPlace to a variable at second last line, and then print that variable in console. It should work.

Comment: please look at the function reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue); I want to build a similar function

Answer (score 0):

For each time you want to change the value in a variable, it needs to be called out again in the form of a declaration. Therefore, output of your function needs to be declared as new value for variable x. Like below:

**Your function**

```
// Writing similar function for a single variable

function changeInPlace(a) {
  a += 5;
  return a;
}
let x = 20;
changeInPlace(x);
console.log(x);
// x should come out as 25
```

**Mine**

```
// Writing similar function for a single variable

function changeInPlace(a) {
  return a += 5; // Made a small tweak to your function,
}
let x = 20;
x = changeInPlace(x); // this stores the output of the function in the same variable
console.log(x);
```

This should give you the desired output, assume this is what you've been asking for if otherwise let me know

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Marijn (author of eloquentJS):
You can't change numbers in JavaScript, only create new ones, so there's no way for a function to change the value of a binding whose *value* is passes as argument to that function. See for example this section in the book: https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#h_C3n45IkMhg